# jQuery validator bypass validation of a certain field in form

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I can't figure out how to bypass a form field inside a form when a certain button is clicked.

Example:

In my case, I want to bypass the `newpassword` and `newpassword2` (which is needed if the user wants to change password) because I have a button so the user can delete his account. Without bypass, he has to fill in a `newpassword` and confirm it before he can delete his account.

These are the id's:

- Delete button: `deletemyacc`
- Form name: `updelacc` (because update / delete account option within this form)
- Form field names to bypasss: `newpassword` and `newpassword2`

Now this code works, but it skips ALL validations, while I still want the `old password` form field to be validated and the users `email`.

```
$("#deletemyacc").click(function () {
  $("#updelacc").validate().cancelSubmit = true;
});
```

Comment: Show your HTML and the rest of your jQuery so we can better help.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("#deletemyacc").click(function () {
  $("#updelacc").validate({ignore: ".ignore"}).cancelSubmit = true;
});
```

this way ignores all elements with class 'ignore'

Source: http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options